# In what way is fcntl.lockf() locking a file?

Tags: python, locking, fcntl

I'm currently attempting to lock a file via python so other processes cannot even read it.

So far i was testing behavior of fcntl.lockf() via python interpreter:

```
>>> file = open("/path/to/file", "w")
>>> fcntl.lockf(file.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl_LOCK_READ)
```

I've tried this and few other variations of fcntl.lockf but still i was able to open the file second time and obtain his fd.
I was able to read it and also write to it.

Am I missing something or this should not lock the file for other procesess at all? Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an advisory lock, that is only a cooperating process will be deterred. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062466/mandatory-file-lock-on-linux) on how to place a mandatory lock.

Comment: By cooperating processes you mean processes which will assume, that there might be a lock and will act accordingly?

Comment: Yes; the process cooperates if it also calls `lockf`.